# Python Request Returns OSError 403 Forbidden with Proxies on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-requests, http-status-code-403, proxies

I've spent countless hours trying to resolve the below issue and whilst I've narrowed down the issue, I've yet to find a solution.

The code runs fine on Windows 10 with no errors, however, when running on Ubuntu around 1/50-100 requests produce the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.my-ip.io/ip', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

The code I am using for testing:

```
import requests
from time import sleep

url = "https://api.my-ip.io/ip"
proxyList = [
'http://user:pass@ip:port',
'http://user:pass@ip:port',
'http://user:pass@ip:port'
]

def startTest():
    while True:
        for proxy in proxyList:
            r = requests.get(url, proxies={'https':proxy}, timeout=20)
            print(f"[Status: {r.status_code}] - [Resp: {r.text}] - [Proxy: {proxy}]")
            sleep(1)
startTest()
```

To clarify, here are some further details:

- This error seems persistent with several websites/apis I've tried so doesn't seem to be the site
- I've tried running both Windows & Linux on the same local IP to eliminate my server being the issue
- Both Windows & Linux were running the same Python version
- It's not a select bad proxy in the list which produces the error

The proxies are paid for (which is why I've redacted that info). I do not have access to the configuration, however, besides headers which I've already tried spoofing (maybe badly), I cannot understand what the difference would be with running the code on Windows vs Linux on the same network.

Any help would be appreciated.